# Can I change someone else's display name?

Tags: google-talk

Some contacts in my Google Talk list are showing their username instead of their full name. Is there a possibility to show their full name instead? I don't like the strange names in between.

I am using the Google Talk web interface that's on the left of Gmail.

Comment: Yes; this is maddening for me, with some people who have ridiculous display names and I really want to straighten them up.

Comment: Gosh, up until today (20/3/15) I'm still searching for this very basic function. There are people in my list using ridiculous name attached to their google+ profile. And the emails keep showing that "hey you got email from Batman (for example)". And I got a hard time thinking who the hell is this Batman... Changing contact details does no help.

Comment: One awkward way is to delete & add them back in with the format "display name" <email-address>.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - just edit the contact from your contact's list.

Go to contacts 
Search the user name 
Select & edit the contact

Note that the name displayed on emails will be the name appearing in the sender's address book. Also, I'd you've enabled chat with G+, the profile names may appear too.

Comment: The contact in my list has a full name and there is no short display name in it or something. The display name on the e-mails is also the full name of the user. So the only place where it goes wrong is the chat contacts list. I don't have a G+ account.

Answer (score 3):

Although the contact info is changed, the previous username keep popping up when the email address is put in. I think it's a bug. There is no way to change the username.

Answer (score 0):

Three simple steps to get it done:

1. Search contact from gmail contact list
2. Select person's profile (eg john's profile)
3. Double click on Name and edit,no need to save it